# If you associate a Microsoft Account with a Local Account in Windows 8, will it maintain the original Local USERPROFILE path name?

Tags: windows, windows-8, user-accounts, environment-variables, user-profiles

If you choose to use a Local Account, you get a nice "clean" USERPROFILE path of:

C:\Users\username

If you then associate a Microsoft Account to that Local Account, will it maintain the original USERPROFILE path created above by the Local Account or will it try to CHANGE the USERPROFILE path to what it uses when using ONLY a Microsoft Account without a Local Account?

**Example - When adding an MS Account to Local Account will it try to change USERPROFILE:**

- C:\Users\bill

to

- C:\Users\first_five_chars_of_email+three_digit_counter (C:\Users\bgate_000)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why you think it would try to change it, but associating a Windows 8 account to an MS account, or disassociating it, doesn't modify the user's profile path (I actually just did this myself today).

Comment: Because I didn't know if all the background Microsoft Account sync magic had some sort of reliance on path management that it controlled across multiple devices.  Glad to know you have tried and it left your path alone.